# Client Component data not showing when i deployed my nextjs 14 app on aws amplify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, next.js, wp-graphql

i am building a webapp with nextjs 14 and using wordpress as headless CMS. One of my pages which purely renders a Client component does not show or fetch the data when i deploy the app on aws but shows and fetch the data on my local machine. I have read the nextjs 14 documentation on CSR and SSR but i cant seem to solve the problem.

I would like to know if it is wrong to fetch data in a client component and render it

This is my Page component

```
export default async function CaseStudies() {
  return (
    <>
      <CaseStudyClient />
    </>
  );
}
```

This is my client component where i fetch and use the data

```
"use client";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const BATCH_SIZE = 2;

function CaseStudyClient({ searchParams }) {
  const [industries, setIndustries] = useState([]);
  const [selectedIndustry, setSelectedIndustry] = useState("");
  const [caseStudyData, setCaseStudyData] = useState([]);
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState("DESC");
  const [pageInfo, setPageInfo] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const selectedIndustryNoSpaces = selectedIndustry.replace(/\s+/g, "");

  const handleIndustryChange = (event) => {
    setSelectedIndustry(event.target.value);
  };

  const query = searchParams?.query || "";

  function handleChange(event) {
    setSelectedOption(event.target.value);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchInitialData() {
      console.log("initial data");

      setLoading(true);

      let casestudies = await getAllCStudies(
        "",
        BATCH_SIZE,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        selectedOption,
        "DATE",
        query
      );

      // let industriesData = await GetTags();
      let data = await getCaseStudyCategories();
      // console.log(data.edges[0].node.children.edges, "CASE CAT");
      setCaseStudyData(casestudies.nodes);
      setPageInfo(casestudies.pageInfo);
      setIndustries(data.edges[0].node.children.edges);
      setLoading(false);
    }
    fetchInitialData();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchPostsByCategory() {
      setLoading(true);
      try {
        let data;

        // Check if 'Allcategories' is selected
        if (selectedIndustry === "") {
          data = await getAllCStudies(
            "",
            BATCH_SIZE,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            selectedOption,
            "DATE"
          );
        } else if (selectedIndustry) {
          data = await getAllCStudies(
            selectedIndustryNoSpaces,
            BATCH_SIZE,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            selectedOption,
            "DATE"
          );
        }

        if (query) {
          data = await getAllCStudies(
            selectedIndustryNoSpaces,
            BATCH_SIZE,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            selectedOption,
            "DATE",
            query
          );
        }

        if (data) {
          setCaseStudyData(data.nodes);
          setPageInfo(data.pageInfo);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching case studies:", error);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    }
    fetchPostsByCategory();
  }, [selectedIndustry, selectedOption, query]);

  const handleNext = async () => {
    if (pageInfo.hasNextPage) {
      let newPosts = await getAllCStudies(
        selectedIndustryNoSpaces,
        BATCH_SIZE,
        pageInfo.endCursor,
        null,
        null,
        selectedOption,
        "DATE"
      );

      setCaseStudyData(newPosts?.nodes);
      setPageInfo(newPosts?.pageInfo);
    }
  };

  const handlePrevious = async () => {
    if (pageInfo.hasPreviousPage) {
      let newPosts = await getAllCStudies(
        selectedIndustryNoSpaces,
        null,
        null,
        BATCH_SIZE,
        pageInfo.startCursor,
        selectedOption,
        "DATE"
      );

      setCaseStudyData(newPosts?.nodes);
      setPageInfo(newPosts?.pageInfo);
    }
  };

  console.log(caseStudyData);
  console.log(selectedIndustry);
  console.log(selectedIndustryNoSpaces);
  return (
    <>
      <Box display={{ mobile: "none", portraitTab: "block" }}>
        <CaseStudyCarousel />
      </Box>

      <Container className="" sx={{}}>
        <CustomContainer>
          <Box paddingTop={"3rem"}>
            <HomeIcon>
              <Link href={"/casestudies"}>
                {" "}
                <Typography
                  variant="body1"
                  fontSize={{ mobile: "1.6rem", portraitTab: "1.4rem" }}
                  fontWeight={"500"}
                >
                  Case Studies{" "}
                </Typography>
              </Link>
            </HomeIcon>
          </Box>
          <Box marginTop={"5rem"} marginBottom={"7.4rem"}>
            <Box
              display={"flex"}
              justifyContent={"space-between"}
              flexDirection={{ mobile: "column", portraitTab: "row" }}
              gap={{ mobile: "2rem", portraitTab: "" }}
            >
              <Typography
                variant="h2"
                fontSize={{ mobile: "3.8rem", portraitTab: "3.2rem" }}
                fontWeight={"500"}
                className="text-midnight-blue"
              >
                Key Solutions We Provided To Top Businesses
              </Typography>
              <Box sx={{ minWidth: "20rem" }}>
                <FormControl fullWidth>
                  <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">
                    Clusters
                  </InputLabel>
                  <Select
                    labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
                    id="demo-simple-select"
                    value={selectedIndustry}
                    label="All Categories"
                    onChange={handleIndustryChange}
                  >
                    <MenuItem value="">
                      <em>industries</em>
                    </MenuItem>

                    {industries &&
                      industries.map((item, index) => {
                        return (
                          <MenuItem key={index} value={item.node.name}>
                            {item?.node.name.replace(
                              /([a-z])([A-Z])/g,
                              "$1 $2"
                            )}
                          </MenuItem>
                        );
                      })}
                  </Select>
                </FormControl>
              </Box>
            </Box>

            <Box
              display={"flex"}
              flexDirection={{
                mobile: "column",
                portraitTab: "row",
              }}
              marginBottom={"3rem"}
              marginTop={"3rem"}
              justifyContent={"space-between"}
            >
              <Box
                display={"flex"}
                flexDirection={{
                  mobile: "column",
                  portraitTab: "row",
                }}
                flex={1}
                justifyContent={"space-between"}
                gap={"3rem"}
              >
                {" "}
                <Box flex={1}>
                  <Search />
                </Box>
                <Box
                  display={"flex"}
                  alignItems={"center"}
                  flex={1}
                  gap={"2rem"}
                >
                  <Typography
                    variant="h3"
                    fontSize={{ mobile: "1.8rem", portraitTab: "1.6rem" }}
                    className={`text-grayish-blue ${openSans.className}`}
                    style={{ fontWeight: "normal" }}
                  >
                    Sort By:
                  </Typography>
                  <Box sx={{ width: "20rem" }} flex={1}>
                    <FormControl fullWidth>
                      <Select
                        labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
                        id="demo-simple-select"
                        value={selectedOption}
                        label="Sort Post"
                        onChange={handleChange}
                      >
                        <MenuItem value="DESC">
                          <Typography
                            variant="h3"
                            fontSize={{
                              mobile: "1.6rem",
                              portraitTab: "1.4rem",
                            }}
                            className={`text-grayish-blue ${openSans.className}`}
                            style={{ fontWeight: "normal" }}
                          >
                            Newest Case Studies
                          </Typography>
                        </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem value="ASC">
                          <Typography
                            variant="h3"
                            fontSize={{
                              mobile: "1.6rem",
                              portraitTab: "1.4rem",
                            }}
                            className={`text-grayish-blue ${openSans.className}`}
                            style={{ fontWeight: "normal" }}
                          >
                            Least Recent Case Studies
                          </Typography>
                        </MenuItem>
                      </Select>
                    </FormControl>
                  </Box>
                </Box>
              </Box>

              <Box
                flex={0.5}
                display={{
                  mobile: "none",
                  portraitTab: "flex",
                }}
                justifyContent={"flex-end"}
              >
                <Box
                  width={"15rem"}
                  display={"flex"}
                  justifyContent={"space-between"}
                  alignItems={"center"}
                >
                  <Box>
                    {" "}
                    <svg
                      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                      fill="none"
                      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                      strokeWidth={1.5}
                      stroke="currentColor"
                      className="w-6 h-6"
                      color={"#3768B0"}
                      onClick={handlePrevious}
                      disabled={pageInfo && !pageInfo.hasPreviousPage}
                      width={"3rem"}
                      style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                    >
                      <path
                        strokeLinecap="round"
                        strokeLinejoin="round"
                        d="M6.75 15.75 3 12m0 0 3.75-3.75M3 12h18"
                      />
                    </svg>
                  </Box>

                  <Box>
                    <svg
                      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                      fill="none"
                      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                      strokeWidth={1.5}
                      stroke="currentColor"
                      className="w-6 h-6"
                      color={"#3768B0"}
                      width={"3rem"}
                      style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                      onClick={handleNext}
                      disabled={pageInfo && !pageInfo.hasNextPage}
                    >
                      <path
                        strokeLinecap="round"
                        strokeLinejoin="round"
                        d="M17.25 8.25 21 12m0 0-3.75 3.75M21 12H3"
                      />
                    </svg>
                  </Box>
                </Box>
              </Box>
            </Box>

            {loading ? (
              "loading"
            ) : (
              <Box
                display={"grid"}
                gridTemplateColumns={{
                  mobile: "repeat(1 , 1fr)",
                  portraitTab: "repeat(2 , 1fr)",
                }}
                gap={"2.5rem"}
                marginTop={"5rem"}
              >
                {caseStudyData.map((item, index) => {
                  console.log(item);
                  return (
                    <Box flex={1} key={index}>
                      {" "}
                      <ImagewithSubtitle
                        src={item.casestudies.mainimage?.mediaItemUrl}
                        subtitle={item.categories?.nodes[0].name.replace(
                          /([a-z])([A-Z])/g,
                          "$1 $2"
                        )}
                        alt={item?.title}
                        // xsWidth={"100%"}
                        // mdWidth={"31.4rem"}
                        xsHeight={"35rem"}
                        mdHeight={"25rem"}
                        color={"#3768B0"}
                        fontWeight={"normal"}
                        iconWidth={"2.5rem"}
                        xsText={"2.4rem"}
                        mdText={"1.8rem"}
                        noArrow={true}
                        textBgColor={"white"}
                        noHover={true}
                        // link={true}
                        // linkUrl={image.linkUrl}
                      />
                      <Box
                        sx={{
                          padding: "3rem 0",
                          paddingLeft: "1rem",
                          marginTop: "-2rem",
                        }}
                      >
                        <Typography
                          variant="body1"
                          paddingTop={"0.3rem"}
                          fontSize={{
                            mobile: "1.9rem",
                            portraitTab: "1.6rem",
                          }}
                          className={`color-primary-bold `}
                          style={{ fontWeight: "normal" }}
                        >
                          {item?.title}
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography
                          variant="body1"
                          padding={"1.1rem 0"}
                          fontSize={{
                            mobile: "1.9rem",
                            portraitTab: "1.6rem",
                          }}
                          className={`text-grayish-blue ${openSans.className}`}
                          style={{ fontWeight: "normal" }}
                        >
                          {item.casestudies.description}
                        </Typography>

                        <Link href={`/casestudies/${item?.slug}`}>
                          <Typography
                            variant="body1"
                            fontSize={{
                              mobile: "1.9rem",
                              portraitTab: "1.6rem",
                            }}
                            sx={{
                              "&:hover": {
                                textDecoration: "underline",
                              },
                            }}
                            className={`color-primary-light ${openSans.className}`}
                            style={{ fontWeight: "normal" }}
                          >
                            Learn about their customer journey
                          </Typography>
                        </Link>
                      </Box>
                    </Box>
                  );
                })}
              </Box>
            )}
            <Box
              flex={0.5}
              display={"flex"}
              justifyContent={"flex-end"}
              marginTop={"5rem"}
            >
              <Box
                width={"15rem"}
                display={"flex"}
                justifyContent={"space-between"}
                alignItems={"center"}
              >
                <Box>
                  {" "}
                  <svg
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    fill="none"
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                    strokeWidth={1.5}
                    stroke="currentColor"
                    className="w-6 h-6"
                    color={"#3768B0"}
                    onClick={handlePrevious}
                    disabled={pageInfo && !pageInfo.hasPreviousPage}
                    width={"3rem"}
                    style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                  >
                    <path
                      strokeLinecap="round"
                      strokeLinejoin="round"
                      d="M6.75 15.75 3 12m0 0 3.75-3.75M3 12h18"
                    />
                  </svg>
                </Box>

                <Box>
                  <svg
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    fill="none"
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                    strokeWidth={1.5}
                    stroke="currentColor"
                    className="w-6 h-6"
                    color={"#3768B0"}
                    width={"3rem"}
                    style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                    onClick={handleNext}
                    disabled={pageInfo && !pageInfo.hasNextPage}
                  >
                    <path
                      strokeLinecap="round"
                      strokeLinejoin="round"
                      d="M17.25 8.25 21 12m0 0-3.75 3.75M21 12H3"
                    />
                  </svg>
                </Box>
              </Box>
            </Box>
          </Box>
        </CustomContainer>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
}

export default CaseStudyClient;
```